# Why does R.O.B. wear "glasses"?

Tags: nes, nintendo

So recently, I've been playing [Gyromite](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i9IOnosRPvU) (which sucks), with [R.O.B.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R.O.B.) (which also sucks), and I noticed that he comes with sunglasses that he doesn't actually need to work properly. This was the case when tested on several different monitors, as well as brightnesses. Where they just added in to look cool?

R.O.B. w/out sunglasses (I do not own this image):
[image: R.O.B. w/out sunglasses]

R.O.B.'s removable sunglasses (I do not own this image):
[image: R.O.B.'s sunglasses]
<sub>(source: [goliath.com](https://cld.goliath.com/image/upload/t_cn,f_auto,q_auto,$w_800/go/2018/05/712YEbD0ubL._AC_SL1500_-730x336.jpg))</sub>

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If this is about the filters supplied with the physical [R.O.B. Unit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R.O.B.), that came with the US only Deluxe [NES](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nintendo_Entertainment_System) set, then it was meant for use with overly bright TV settings. Something that was found necessary after tests had been made in department stores with their often very bright screen settings.

Most important: It looks cool :))

Answer (score 3):

Back in the day, adjustable lenses were either rare, or nonexistent, so R.O.B.'s glasses were basically just his own removable lenses for brighter TV screens. (As stated in TheGamingHistorian's [video on R.O.B.](https://youtu.be/w2FuHErzhVE?t=760))